# cmake add_custom_target won't allow if-statements?

Tags: cmake

is it possible to use if-statements in one command in `add_custom_target`? I came up with

```
add_custom_target(target                 
             if(linux)
               message("Linux!")
             endif()
)
```

but it fails with:

`/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "then")` .

When I add `then` at the end of `if(linux)`, it fails with:

`/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

Why does that not work? Is it not possible to make tests in add_custom_target? My intent is to do different things in add_custom_target depending on the operating system. I also thought about defining a function that is called in add_custom_target, but that doesn't work either. That appproach won't allow me to write a plain `make` which is problematic as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving the code into a cmake-script and calling this script in add_custom_target by cmake's script processing mode: `cmake -P`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the if statements outside `ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET`:

```
if(linux)
    add_custom_target(target message("Linux!"))
elseif(win32)
    add_custom_target(target message("Windows!"))
endif()
```

Comment: I tried to avoid this, as there is much code that is the same for windows and linux. Code duplication is bad!